# webstorm is fetching even deleted files

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I am using webstorm to load a project via sftp.

The remotely mapped directory had some files, which have been deleted via ssh from terminal.

These files still show up in the project, even If I try synchronizing the project dir with server, or download from server options.

The problem persists even if I create new projects, after delete existing ones.

ALso when I am creating a new project and trying to set project root at the dir in the server, when I go along the path to selecting that dir, all other dirs are not shown.

my remote path on server is `~/Desktop/jekyll_files`

I have other directories on Desktop in the server, but these dont show up when I navigate to the `jekyll_files` dir

Comment: Maybe you are connecting to the wrong remote folder / symlink?  P.S. Have you tried contacting JetBrains support directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem unrelated to webstorm